# Counting Integer Occurrence in a 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, count

Given user input, I am trying to count the number of occurrences of the integers in a 2D array in Java.  I got this to work with a one-dimensional array and thought I could just refactor the code to make it work with a 2D array. My code runs, but I can't get it to work. Can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

```
package test.code;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create new scanner object
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Declare two dimentional array
        int[][] num2d = new int[4][3];
        int[][] duplicate = new int[4][3];

        //Declare variables
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        int count;
        final int x = -1;
        //Print to screen asking for user input
        System.out.print("Enter seven numbers: ");

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                num2d[i][j] = userInput.nextInt();
                duplicate[i][j] = x;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                count = 1;
                for (k = i + 1; k < 10; k++) {
                    if (num2d[i][k] == num2d[j][k]) {
                        count++;
                        duplicate[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (duplicate[i][j] != 0) {
                    duplicate[i][j] = count;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (duplicate[i][j] != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Number " + num2d[i][j] + " occurs " + duplicate[i][j] + " times.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you only want to know the total number of duplicates in the `num2d` array or do you also want to know the exact indices where duplicates occur? Do you only want to know the number of 1s, 2s, 3s and so on in the `num2d` array? What is the purpose of the `duplicate` array?

Comment: If you could give an example of input and expected output it will help to understand.

Comment: QMarkusAnd.  I just want to count the duplicate numbers and print out the number and how many times it occurred.  I used the duplicate array in other code. as a means to count the occurrences.  I initially set all values of the duplicates array to -1.  As the loop iterated over the array, it marked the index with a 0 so it doesn't count twice.

Comment: @Lovesh Dongre - Given user input of 7 numbers (1 2 3 1 2 3 4) Count the number of occurrences of each integer using a 2d array without hash maps.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you only want the exact number of occurrences for each individual integer in `num2d`.

For this I would use the data structure `Map`, [see docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Now you can transform your 2d array to a `Map`. The duplicates will be stored in the `Map` where the keys are the integer value and map values are the number of instances for that integer.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> duplicates = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
int currentIntValue;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      currentIntValue = num2d[i][j]);      
      if(duplicates.KeySet().contains(currentIntValue)) {
         duplicates.put(currentIntValue, duplicates.get(currentIntValue) + 1); //Integer already in map, inc the count value
      } else 
      {
         duplicates.put(currentIntValue, 1); //Integer not in map, add it with count 1
      }
      
   }
}
```

Now you can easily get the count for an integer by the line

```
duplicates.get(1); //Will return the count for integer 1
```

However this makes the 2D redudndant and you could more easily just loop through the number of `userInput` instead of adding them to an 2D array first, I don't really understand the purpose of `num2d`.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not allowed to use hash maps for this.  I must count using a 2D array and not a one-dimensional array. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Okay, please include such details when you ask your question. The more details the better. I think maps are the best way to store this kind of information and it seems clumsy and unnecessarily hard to use a 2D-array but I guess that it is not you who made those limitations.

Comment: Yes.  I apologize.  I should have point that out in the initial post.